# Join with "AND" instead of "OR" in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I have this query:

```
res = Model1.joins(:items).where(items: {id: [1, 2, 3]}).uniq
```

which queries records by "OR" because it compiles into "where id in(?)". How should I change it so that it **becomes** "AND"?

Comment: can you explain why you want this?

Comment: it makes no sense but it's possible: Model.joins(:items).where('items.id = ? AND items.id = ? AND items.id = ?', 1, 2, 3) . I think you don't really want to achieve this though , this won't return any results.

Comment: @Joel_Blum, it should be dynamic, how?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Include all ids in ActiveRecord query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37071651/include-all-ids-in-activerecord-query)

Answer (score 0):

You can try something of this sort (prepare your item_ids in advance somehow):

```
  join_relation = Model1.joins(:items)
  item_ids.each do |id| 
     join_relation.where(items: {id: id} } 
  end
  res = join_relation.uniq
```